# While use TextInputEditText, the error icon override the end icon

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am developing an interface that contains a component TextInputLayout.
Here is my layout code:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:id="@+id/username_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/icons8_user_24"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icons8_user_24"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:hint="Enter UserName"
        android:textColorHint="@color/teal_200">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and here is the java code:

```
    UsereditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s != null && !isEmailAddress(s.toString())) {
                UsereditText.setError("Error Address");
            } else {
                UsereditText.setError(null);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

and result image is:

[image]

However, I saw someone did it perfectly, don't know how.

[image]

I am emo now, please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Which view are you binding with "UsereditText"? The TextInputLayout or the TextInputEditText?

Comment: Sorry for this, the "UsereditText" binds with TextInputEditText.

Comment: see my updated answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER** (after more info added)

Try calling the setError() on the `TextInputLayout` instead of the `TextInputEditText`. The view itself will then make sure that the error icon doesn't overlap with the end icon.

---

<strike>Don't place the edit icon as a background drawable, try putting it as `drawableEnd` instead:</strike>

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: Hi, the background I set in the edit text is just transparent not an icon, the way I put the icon at the end is app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icons8_user_24". However, I try your method, the error icon will  instead the previous icon.

Comment: By this method, the error icon will instead the end icon. But, I wonder how to get the result as the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

**Update Answer**

Actually, I'm following this XML code below

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/enter_mail_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/mail"
                        style="@style/TextViewStyleRegular"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:hint="@string/enter_mail_2"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
                        android:maxLength="50" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Kotlin Code**

```
binding.enterMailText.setErrorIconDrawable(R.drawable.no_icon)
        binding.enterMailText.error = "Please enter valid email address"
```

**no_icon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

binding.yourInputLayout.errorIconDrawable = null